# Why can't I retract my reopen vote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-reopen

On [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99102/storing-object-pointers-in-a-thread-safe-way), I voted to reopen after the second edit. I later realized that I shouldn't have voted to reopen, but I can't take it back. It seems the functionality doesn't exist.

[image: No Retract Reopen vote]

If I click "OK" it says that I have already voted, and if I click "Cancel" it closes the alert:

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes